# will creating a static folder in the root directory serve the purpose of loading the static content from cookieless domain?

Tags: cookies, ftp

I am been optimizing my site and following the steps on tools.pingdom.com. It says here to serve all my static content from a cookieless domain or subdomain. Now i do not have the authority to create a new sub domain for my site. All I have is an FTP access.

So will the following idea serve the purpose of loading static content from a cookieless domain:
1) create a folder in the root directory via ftp access as this folder wont be recognized by wordpress
2) store all the static content in it and load it from there

Answer (score 1):

No it won't. If the domain name is still the same then cookies issued by WP will still be passed back and forth between browser and server.

Comment: Thanks alot. Any way i can create a sub-domain from within wordpress or any other solution ? I only have an ftp access

Comment: No. You need your web server to respond to the second hostname so either your host ISP needs to add it for you or you need that level of control over your hosting. You'll also need to be able to configure WP to use this second hostname for links to static media.

Comment: thanks again. I was gonna follow this tutorial for configuring WP https://www.itsupportguides.com/wordpress/wordpress-how-to-serve-static-content-from-a-cookieless-domain/